# How to get around RPM size limit?

Tags: linux, rpmbuild

I'm building quite big RPM (~5Gb) and getting following message:

```
`error: Package too large (> 2147483647 bytes)`
```

Is there a way to ignore this limit? I'm using RPM 4.4.2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can split package to more packages less 2Gb.

Comment: thanks, that sounds like an option, but I was hoping for more elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is a restriction that applies to RPM Version 4.4 which you'll find in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5. I can verify that this restriction does not apply when running rpm-4.8.0-27.el6.x86_64 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.3.

I've successfully build and signed a RPM with the size of 5.2GB on RHEL6.3 with above mentioned version of RPM.

A side note, even if there are cases where you end up with a RPM with such a size (for example, if you are packaging IBM WebSphere), if your RPM gets above 1GB - that is normally an indication that what you are trying to do - is wrong :-) For example you may be packaging large image files or zip archives inside of an RPM, something that works against the purpose of RPM.